# Golang - curl my endpoint from workspace terminal

Tags: go, curl, eclipse-che

I am trying to set up a REST endpoint in Go in the **Eclipse-Che** workspace

My code is shown below:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
        log.Println("Hello world1")
    })
    http.HandleFunc("/goodbye", func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
        log.Println("Goodbye world")
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":8085", nil)
}
```

On running my go code, I'm getting the following output.

```
bash-4.4 /projects/src/github.com/golang $ curl -V 10.130.54.6/8084
curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.52.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2u zlib/1.2.8 libidn2/0.16 libpsl/0.17.0 (+libidn2/0.16) libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.18.1 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL 
bash-4.4 /projects/src/github.com/golang $ curl -V http://10.130.54.6/8084
curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.52.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2u zlib/1.2.8 libidn2/0.16 libpsl/0.17.0 (+libidn2/0.16) libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.18.1 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two problem with your request:

- You aren not sending a request to your webserver (IP/NUMBER describe a subnet) .
- You are using `-V` instead of `-v` (that show the version of the `cURL` tool).

Try with:

```sh
curl -v 127.0.0.1:8085
#curl -v 0.0.0.0:8085 will also work
```

This because you are running the software in your machine, binding the service at port `8085`

If your firewall is open, you can query the service from another machine in the same network using:

```sh
curl -v 10.130.54.6:8084
```

You can retrieve your internal ip using `ifconfig`, and checking which device (`eth0`, `lo` ecc) are you using for access to internet.